# How to undo the changes made in original DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, drop

I am working with a dataset. As a precautionary measure, I created a back-up copy using the following command.

Orig. Dataframe = df

df_copy = df.copy(deep = True)

Now, I dropped few columns from original dataframe (df) by mistake using inplace = True.
I tried to undo the operation, but no use.

So, the question is how to get my original dataframe (df) from copied dataframe (df_copy) ?

Comment: you said you created a backup of the data. Create a new backup and use one of the copies as your restored data. do `df = df_copy(deep = True)` and you will have `df` restored to original from the backup copy

Answer (score 0):

Yoy cannot restore it. Code like below dosen't work.

df = df_copy.copy(deep = True)

Every variables which reference original df keep reference after operation above.

Comment: This is not an anser to OPs question - you can put that in comment below the question